# AnonymousPipeServerStream.Read() occasionally hangs on client exit

Tags: c#, .net, windows, debugging, pipe

I have a master and a slave program who interact through a pair of anonymous pipes.

The interaction looks like this:

- Master creates two AnonymousPipeServerStream's
- Master starts client process, giving him their .GetClientHandleAsString()
- Master .DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle's both pipes
- Master writes stuff to one pipe and reads stuff from the other one
- Occasionally master forcefully terminates the slave from another thread (Process.Kill()), AND ALSO closes both pipe objects.

In very rare circumstances, upon slave termination, **reading from the pipe on master's side blocks indefinitely** - or sometimes definitely (e.g. for several minutes). I am not able to reproduce it on my local machine, but it happens from time to time on a large cluster.

I captured a dump of this situation, and here's what I saw:

Stacktrace of blocked master (I am 100% sure that at this moment the client process is already terminated):

```
000000000c83e488 000000007700fdba [NDirectMethodFrameStandalone: 000000000c83e488] Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ReadFile(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePipeHandle, Byte*, Int32, Int32 ByRef, IntPtr)
000000000c83e430 000007feeab32820 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePipeHandle, Byte*, Int32, Int32 ByRef, IntPtr)*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Core.ni.dll

000000000c83e540 000007feeac14574 System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.ReadFileNative(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePipeHandle, Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*, Int32 ByRef)
000000000c83e5a0 000007feeac14a23 System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.ReadCore(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
000000000c83e610 000007fef0169d8f System.IO.BinaryReader.FillBuffer(Int32)
000000000c83e650 000007fef0169c8a System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadInt32()
```

I also looked at the AnonymousPipeServerStream object that's blocking, and at its state and handle.

It has:

- m_state = 4 (i.e. closed)
- m_clientHandle is a closed handle (according to SafeHandle._state and to the output of !handle)
- m_handle is an open handle, with _state = 6 (i.e. NOT closed, even though the Pipe object is closed and, according to decompilation, it should have called m_handle.Dispose()):

Here's the output of !handle for the master-side handle.

```
0:000> !handle 1850 ff
Handle 0000000000001850
  Type          File
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x120189:
         ReadControl,Synch
         Read/List,ReadEA,ReadAttr,WriteAttr
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  5
  No object specific information available
```

I am a bit worried that the HandleCount is 2 and PointerCount is 5.

Any ideas what could have gone wrong? Why was the master's end of the reading handle not closed when I closed the pipe? Why was the pipe not broken, despite the client termination and despite the fact I called DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle?

What can I do to at least work around this? Maybe just do Thread.Interrupt on the reading thread?..

Comment: How do you start the child process? What is the value bInheritHandles parameter?

Comment: I do not indicate it explicitly. But I do mark the pipe handles as inheritable of course (in the constructor of AnonymousPipeServerStream)

Comment: Since dependency is ultimately on the pipes, can you have threads needing the pipes be released by an event triggered by the closing of the said pipes? Just a thought.

Comment: @jkff This was an interesting question.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: @arx Unfortunately not - the solution was to roll back my program to using stdin/stdout transport. Thread.Interrupt doesn't work here, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Possible sequence of events in master process, preceded by thread numbers:

- 1 - About to call Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ReadFile (inside BinaryReader.ReadInt32)
- 2 - Kill slave process and close pipe handles
- 3 - The win32 pipe handle (which is now closed) is reused for some other pipe (or file or whatever)
- 1 - Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ReadFile starts reading using the old handle that now refers to some other object, and blocks.

Fix:

Kill the slave process in thread 2 but don't close the handles.  This will cause any read in thread 1 to terminate, then close the pipe handles in thread 1.

Moral:

Don't close handles while you're still using them.